# 5 блоков на всю ширину экрана

Tags: css3, html5

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, не знаю, как подступиться. Нужно сделать, чтобы все 5 фото были на всю ширину экрана. Подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сейчас что с ними не так?

Comment: На картинке psd файл.
Сейчас я просто не знаю как вообще сделать такое.